# How to automatically move *.pb.h and *.pb.h under /include and /src directories?

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I am developing a library which uses Google Protocol Buffers (`protobuf`) and CMake. The project has the following directory tree.

```
MyProject/
MyProject/include/myproject/
MyProject/include/myproject/some_classes.h
MyProject/src/
MyProject/src/some_classes.cc
MyProject/src/foo.proto
MyProject/CMakeList.txt
```

`CMakeList.txt` has the following lines to generate protobuf source and header files.

```
include_directories(${libCHEC_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src SOURCES)

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
file(GLOB ProtoFiles "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.proto")
protobuf_generate_cpp(ProtoSources ProtoHeaders ${ProtoFiles})
list(APPEND EXTLIBS ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})

add_library(MyLibrary SHARED ${SOURCES} ${ProtoSources})
target_link_libraries(MyLibrary ${EXTLIBS})
```

When I execute `cmake`, `foo.pb.h` and `foo.pb.cc` are generated under the build directory (i.e. the directory where I executed `cmake`). It looks that this is the default behavior. But I would like to put `foo.pb.h` and `foo.pb.cc` under `include/myproject` and `src` directories, respectively.

How can I change the locations of the files generated by `protoc`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I added `MyProject/misc/myprotobuf.cmake` which had a modified version of `PROTOBUF_GENERAGE_CPP`.

```
function(MY_PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP PATH SRCS HDRS)
  if(NOT ARGN)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Error: PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP() called without any proto files")
    return()
  endif()

  if(PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP_APPEND_PATH)
    # Create an include path for each file specified
    foreach(FIL ${ARGN})
      get_filename_component(ABS_FIL ${FIL} ABSOLUTE)
      get_filename_component(ABS_PATH ${ABS_FIL} PATH)
      list(FIND _protobuf_include_path ${ABS_PATH} _contains_already)
      if(${_contains_already} EQUAL -1)
          list(APPEND _protobuf_include_path -I ${ABS_PATH})
      endif()
    endforeach()
  else()
    set(_protobuf_include_path -I ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
  endif()

  if(DEFINED PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS)
    foreach(DIR ${PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS})
      get_filename_component(ABS_PATH ${DIR} ABSOLUTE)
      list(FIND _protobuf_include_path ${ABS_PATH} _contains_already)
      if(${_contains_already} EQUAL -1)
          list(APPEND _protobuf_include_path -I ${ABS_PATH})
      endif()
    endforeach()
  endif()

  set(${SRCS})
  set(${HDRS})
  foreach(FIL ${ARGN})
    get_filename_component(ABS_FIL ${FIL} ABSOLUTE)
    get_filename_component(FIL_WE ${FIL} NAME_WE)

    list(APPEND ${SRCS} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PATH}/${FIL_WE}.pb.cc")
    list(APPEND ${HDRS} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PATH}/${FIL_WE}.pb.h")

    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PATH})

    add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PATH}/${FIL_WE}.pb.cc"
             "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PATH}/${FIL_WE}.pb.h"
      COMMAND  ${PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE}
      ARGS --cpp_out  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PATH} ${_protobuf_include_path} ${ABS_FIL}
      DEPENDS ${ABS_FIL}
      COMMENT "Running C++ protocol buffer compiler on ${FIL}"
      VERBATIM )
  endforeach()

  set_source_files_properties(${${SRCS}} ${${HDRS}} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
  set(${SRCS} ${${SRCS}} PARENT_SCOPE)
  set(${HDRS} ${${HDRS}} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

`MyProject/CMakeLists.txt` has the following two lines now.

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/misc/myprotobuf.cmake)
file(GLOB ProtoFiles "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/misc/*.proto")
my_protobuf_generate_cpp(generated_files/myproject ProtoSources ProtoHeaders ${ProtoFiles})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated_files)
```

Answer (score 11):

I would strictly advise *against* placing generated files in the source tree.

CMake puts a lot of effort into separating the build and source trees. Forcing it to give up that separation has several disadvantages. Among the most prominent is the fact that version control will then have to deal with unversioned generated files in the source tree, and furthermore it may no longer be possible to have multiple builds targetting different architectures sharing the same source tree.

A better approach is to keep the files in the binary tree and adjust your `target_include_directories` accordingly. There is no shame in using generated files from the binary tree as sources, so don't hesitate to do it.

Comment: Hi @ComicSansMs Thank you for your help. I do not see any "disadvantages" you wrote. As I am using Subversion for this project, putting foo.pb.h and foo.pb.cc in `svn:ignore` can easily block them to be added to the repository. In addition, we never use multiple-targets build in it.

Since I would like to install all header files in a single directory, for example `/usr/local/include/myproject`, it would be nice if I can generate `foo.pb.h` under `MyProject/include/myproject`.

Comment: @AkiraOkumura What keeps you from adding the generated headers from the binary directory to the install set?

Comment: I would like to put `#include "myproject/foo.pb.h` in other header files, because all header files are installed under `<PREFIX>/include/myproject` later.

Comment: @AkiraOkumura Which will still work. You simply have to maintain the correct directory structure in the build and install trees.

Comment: Please note that `foot.pb.h` is always generated in `CMAKE_CURRENT_BUILD_DIR`. Therefore, I cannot use `#include "myproject/foo.pb.h"` in the other headers in my project.

Comment: @AkiraOkumura, I've added an answer based on the comments here

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the directory structure for your generated protobuf sources by modifying the source directory and cmakelists in a particular way.

**An example:**

```
MyProject/
MyProject/src
MyProject/src/CMakeLists.txt (1)
MyProject/src/ProtoProject/CMakeLists.txt (2)
MyProject/src/ProtoProject/MyProject/foo.proto
```

CMakeLists.txt (1):

```
add_subdirectory(MyProject)

# generated headers
target_include_directories(ProtoProject PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

CMakeLists.txt (2):

```
set(proto_files "foo.proto")
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS ${proto_files})
add_library(ProtoProject STATIC ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS} ${proto_files})
```

**Why this works**

Each call to `add_subdirectory()` adds a directory level to the `$CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIRECTORY` variable. The generated files will end up at `MyProject/src/ProtoProject/MyProject/foo.pb.h` but your include directory will be `MyProject/src/ProtoProject`, so you can include files as `MyProject/foo.pb.h`